# How can I use a dotted path as a property name of a PropertyChangedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

How can I use a dotted path as a property name of a PropertyChangedEventHandler?

```
public class Person
{
    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age;}
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MyControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty PersonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Person", typeof (Person), typeof (MyControl), null);

    private void someMethod()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Person.Age");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    }   
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

But OnPropertyChanged("Person.Age") cannot resolve the symbol.

Is it possible to use a dotted path as a propertyName of OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to use a dotted path, but normally you won't do that. Instead, you would just change the `Age` property and the setter will take care of the rest (in your case I think the line in the setter should be `OnPropertyChanged("Age")`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Age` setter, you should always call `OnPropertyChanged("Age")`.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't meant to be used for sub-properties. You also don't need it on a UserControl, since dependency properties already provide notification. Once you fix your `OnPropertyChanged` call in the `Person` class you should be fine.

You have a couple of options to fix the `Person.Age` setter:

1. Call `OnPropertyChanged("Age")` (and remove the `= null` in the `OnPropertyChanged` signature.
2. If you are targeting .NET 4.5 or later, the preferred solution is to change the `Person.OnPropertyChanged` signature to be `OnPropertyChanged(string [CallerMemberName] propertyName = null)`. Calling `OnPropertyChanged()` from the `Age` setter will then fill set `propertyName` to `Age`. See the [this blog post](http://grenangen.se/node/75) or the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I resolved this problem by calling Person.OnPropertyChanged("Age") in someMethod() in MyControl class.

Comment: I'm glad to hear. XAML bindings can be frustrating when they don't work, especially when they just work most of the time.